# WinEdt/position in a file

Tags: pdftex, windows, winedt

How do I **save** (and restore after reopening) current position in LaTeX file in WInEdt 10.0?

Comment: Isn't this automatic?

Comment: `\newwrite\pieceofpaper \immediate\openout\pieceofpaper=onesheet.txt \immediate\write\pieceofpaper{\the\linenumber} \immediate\closeout\pieceofpaper` :-p